# Hiding text within a button depending on colliding elements

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm looking at creating a fixed navigation bar with is going to be located within a view of my application. The bar will contain 3 elements, a back button, a navigation dropdown and a optional buttons section. These 3 elements are aligned in terms of left, center and right to the navigation bar.

The idea is that the "back" button will actually list what the previous section was e.g "Summary" or "Personal Details". So this text will expand depending on the previous section. The navigation button will also list the section that you are in, same principle as the back button. But this post isn't really focusing on the navigation or optional button elements.

I've linked a basic [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTAWOuHHuO0Gxh8j3Mhx?p=preview) which gives you a general idea of what i'm doing. The idea is when the view port gets small enough (Below 215px width) and the "back" and "navigation" elements collide, and the text contained within the back button will be hidden to just give you the chevron. Currently you can see this is kind of working in CSS but the button still contains width due to the text of the button been pushed under the chevron. The idea would be to just have the width of the chevron if there was no text at all. There is no specific breakpoints to this as the text will be different depending on each section of the application.

I was wondering if it would be possible to do this with just CSS? I know it would be possible with JavaScript but if a CSS solution is available, I'd rather take this route. If there isn't a CSS solution then JS will have to be the way forward.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="back-container">
        <button class="back">
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <span class="text">Back</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation-container">
        <div class="navigation-container-inner">
          <button class="navigation">Navigation</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="plus-container">
        <ul class="plus">+</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.back-container {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.navigation-container {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.plus-container {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;

  text-align: right;
}

button.back {
  height: 32px;
}

button.back .chevron,
.chevron {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 18px;
  background: url(http://games.thediamondjubilee.org/game_images/timeline/black-chevron-left.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

button.back .text {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

ul.plus {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**Edit:** In reference to the people suggesting media queries, Here is a plunker with potential text that could be within the elements. When resizing the browser now below 335px width, you can see the back element and navigation element colliding. When the text disappears, the back button still contains width based on the text contained inside. I would like the back button to shrink down to just the chevron. Remember, the text in these elements are dynamic based on the location the user has traveled from and is currently in.

[Plunker with real variable values within back and navigation button](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPnV5f4x66cDhvagoGfu?p=preview)

**Edit 2:** The solution will want to work in IE10 and 11, chrome, FF and Safari. So don't worry about supporting anything lower in terms of IE.

Comment: Why are you trying to support anything below 215px is there a reason behind this?

You can simply control or show what elements show up using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to show which element shows up on that width and which elements can be hidden.

Comment: @youssef If you viewed the plunker, you could see the collision is below 215px because of the text in the back and navigation buttons. As previously stated this text will change dynamically based on the location the user is within the application. So once you start having larger strings "Personal Details" for example, it will collide at a larger resolution. Instead of "back" which is a small string. Media queries isn't possible because of not knowing where the user will be within the application and the "navigation" and "back" elements will be populated with dynamic text.

Comment: Let me rephrase, you don't need to support a 215px width, check this [link](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/considerations-for-mobile-design-part-2-dimensions/). As you can see the lowest device width stays at 320px which is the iphone (3/4/4s/5) and a couple of other devices, I see no reason behind supporting a 215px width, And it can be done using media queries without any problems as long as the elements don't change then no matter what content is in there, there're a lot of ways to do it with media queries.

Comment: @youssef I'm not bothered about supporting a 215px width device. There will be other surrounding content to the application. Its just that reaching below 215px width in the plunk makes the elements collide, and thus hiding the back text but the button itself still has width to it from the text as it was pushed below.

Comment: @youssef I've added an Edit section to the question, Hopefully this will help clarify where i'm coming from.

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn02zLc0/), I hope this is near what you are looking for.

Comment: @youssef I'm sorry man, This isn't what i'm looking for. Its a step in the right direction but I don't want to implement media queries. If you refer to my plunk in the edit section of the question, You can see there is a range of strings that could be put into the "back" and "navigation" elements. The only time I would like the back button to hide is when the "back" element and "navigation" element collide, as I want the user to be able to see there previous location most of the time but if they do resize and these elements do collide, then hide the text.